# Getting selected value of listbox windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get the text of the selected item of a listbox.
But i should a result of "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem"

My code:
listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

How should i change my code?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800542/getting-information-from-a-data-binding-listbox-for-a-new-page/6800767#6800767

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
if(null != listBox.SelectedItem)
{
    string text = (listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class like

```
    public class Person
    {

       public string Name;
       public string LastName;



    }

//This class can be in a separate file


//to create a list from this to fill the listbox you can use the following code. 


//this can be in the interface part of the app where the value of the selecteditem is selected

Person m = listBoxName.SelectedItem as Person;

string VariableString =  m.Name;
```