# Windows phone 8 saving and open links in web Browser history

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, browser, browser-history

I have a web browser which is storing all the visited websites. There is just one issue, I would like it for the user to click on one of the records and then it should open in the webbrowser.

Once the user has navigated to a page, this method is called with the url:

```
    public List<String> urls;
    public string selectedURL;

        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox.DataContext = urls;
    }

     private void getHistory(string url)
    {
        urls.Add(url);

        listBox.DataContext = null;
        listBox.DataContext = urls;
    }

    private void listBoxtrend_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedURL = "";

        var selected = listBox.SelectedValue as Item;
        selectedText = selected.ItemString;

        MessageBox.Show(selectedURL);
        browserSearch(selectedURL);
    }
```

This is then displayed into a textblock on a pivot page:

```
<phone:Pivot Margin="0,0,0,0">

        <phone:PivotItem Header="" Margin="0,-104,0,0">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="696"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF5E667B" >
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Margin="0,-104,0,0" Header="">


     <Grid>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Item}" Foreground="RoyalBlue" Name="listBox"
TabIndex="10"  Tap="listBox_Tap" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            x:Name="txtHistory" Text="{Binding ItemString}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

I have tried to put a click event, but there is one way to tell which record is being clicked. Is there a way to use the `SelectionChanged` event handler. And is there a better way to store this data, maybe in a array or list which then can be saved to `IsolatedStorage`.

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you would have the data you're going to display within a `Listbox`, I mean the Url's. So that you could easily get whatever the data you want from the clicked item. Make sure that you bind the source for your `Listbox`.

your xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Item}" Foreground="RoyalBlue" 
Height="395" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="12,111,0,0" Name="listBox" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438"
TabIndex="10"  Tap="listBox_Tap" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            x:Name="txtHistory" Text="{Binding ItemString}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And then from your tap event handler of the `Listbox`

```
private async void listBoxtrend_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
selectedText = "";

var selected = listBox.SelectedValue as Item;
selectedText = selected.ItemString;

MessageBox.Show(selectedText);
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("give the url"));//here should be the selectedText
}
```

These can be referable for more:

[Getting selected value of listbox windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883932/)

[LIstbox Selected Item content to textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887829/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, I have added your code but it has come up with a few errors such as: The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found, and The name 'selectedText' does not exist in the current context. I have updated and you can see the code in the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you've give the variable name as selectedURL and then declared it to selectedText. "Item" you have to create in your model class. 
    private int _item;
        public int Item
        {
            get
            {
                return _item;
            }
            set
            {
                _item= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }